# Get all the <li> under particular <div>

Tags: html, web-scraping, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I am using Curl to grab the URL and [SIMPLE HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get the data. I want the data which is under `<li>`. But the problem is there are other `<ul>` and `<li>`'s on the page. And they don't have classes or id's. Here is my `html` code.

```
<div class="parent" id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">
            <p>Text Paragraph</p>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Heading Date Text</li>
                <li>Heading Date Text</li>
                <li>Heading Date Text</li>
                <li>Heading Date Text</li>
                <li>Heading Date Text</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Only the top div has an `id` which is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the result.

```
$html = str_get_html('<div class="parent" id="parent">
<div class="child">
    <div class="grandchild">
        <p>Text Paragraph</p>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Heading Date Text</li>
            <li>Heading Date Text</li>
            <li>Heading Date Text</li>
            <li>Heading Date Text</li>
            <li>Heading Date Text</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>');

foreach($html->find('div#parent ul') as $ul) 
{
   foreach($ul->find('li') as $li) 
   {
        echo $li->plaintext."<br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!! But it is displaying other <ul> <li> as well. In the question I said that there are other <ul> <li> in the page.

Comment: So you need to get the li under this div only?

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the li items with:

```
foreach ($html->find("#parent li") as $li)
    echo $li->plaintext . "\n";
```

There is no need for double iteration over the ULs and then the LIs.

Comment: This is the right way to do it but you need to iterate the way guna suggests.